# How should I conditionally assign based on the existence of a dictionary key?

Tags: python

I've got some Perl code like this:

```
my $match = $matches{$key}
            ? "$matches{$key} was a match!"
            : "There was no match."
```

How is this best rewritten in Python? I'm trying to avoid getting a KeyError.

Comment: Plzsendtehcodez.  You can't synthesize these two answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This.

```
message = "%s was a match"%(matches[key],) if key in matches else "There was no match."
```

Comment: Why is the , necessary in matches[key],  ?

Comment: Can I just say this? message = "%s was a match" % matches[key] if key in matches else "There was no match"

Comment: The comma is not necessary. However, it's good style to always use a tuple as the right argument to % string formatting.

Comment: @Benjamin Peterson: just out of curiosity, why?

Comment: format % tuple is the standard form; (x,) is a singleton tuple.  (x,y)  is a two-tuple ("double"), (z,y,x) is a three-tuple ("triple").  Python can tolerate format % value IF (and only if) the value is not itself a sequence.  Strings are sequences.  So format % (string,) is usually required.

Comment: I don't get it. If i do: x = 'foo' ; "%s" % x ...it seems to return 'foo', which is expected. Doesn't this violate S.Lott's most recent comment?

Comment: @Mike: My mistake -- the ambiguity only arises when trying for format a tuple.  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#id5  Then you need to enclose the tuple to a singleton of it: x=(1,2); "%s"%(x,) is required.